# Is there any limitation on web driver wait period in Selenium2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Is there any limitation on wait period in selenium web driver .

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the answer is NO.

But in my case, the longest wait I utilized, was 10 seconds. You will soon get to the amount of time where you know:

- If the element did not appear yet, It will probably not come up at all
- Also, waiting longer than, say 30 seconds, is generally bad idea. Put your user hat on: Would you wait for service longer than 30 secs?
- Yes, I know that test environments are mostly strip down and underpowered. But still, if it takes really long time to test the service, it gives sense to invest to test environment, or at least do the performance test.

(Example to the last: count the time you spend on waiting. Multiple it by your hourly salary. That much money is company losing simply because they pay you to do nothing. But on other hands, I am tester, and sometimes I do enjoy the good time for book and coffee during "work" waiting for deployment :) )

Comment: You have to watch out if you run your tests on grid. Your waits should always be smaller then hub timeouts.

Comment: @pavel : This was a question asked to me by someone and had to reply him .
He does'nt want to wait fr an element to appear but just want to verify some data manually which may take up some time . But he wants to log in and do some PRE stuff before manual work and then do some POST stuff after his manual work

Comment: As I said: I think that answer is NO, no limit in wait is there. But in my case I had longest time only 10 secs. But when you set up say 5 minutes, it should wait 5 minutes.